# What is the purpose of &= and |= operator in C#

Tags: c#, operators

I'm not sure what these operators are accomplishing:

```
byteInfo[x, y, z] |= (byte)info;
```

as well as:

```
byteInfo[x, y, z] &= (byte)255 - (byte)info;
```

From msdn:

```
class AndAssignment
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int a = 0x0c;
        a &= 0x06;
        Console.WriteLine("0x{0:x8}", a);
        bool b = true;
        b &= false;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
   }
}

/*
Output:
0x00000004
False
*/
```

But, what did it do?

Comment: Nah, those were just a bunch of links all saying the same thing. They were not very helpful as to what the operators are doing to the values and purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are bitwise operators. `&` represents the logical AND operator and `|` the OR. There is also `~` for NOT and `^` for XOR.

In your example, it is simply calculating the AND between two binary values : `1100 AND 0110 = 0100` (Which is 4, as in your output). The second one can be seen as `1 AND 0 = 0`.
You can refer to Truth Tables to see how it works exactly : [AND operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction), [OR operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)

However, one of the most common use is with enumerations. For example, let's say you have the days of the week

```
[Flags]
public enum DaysOfTheWeek
{
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4,
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x16,
    Friday = 0x32,
    Saturday = 0x64
}
```

You can use bitwise operators to easily assign values. For example, if you want to represent the weekend you can use the OR operator to set the binary flags :

```
DaysOfTheWeek weekend = DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday | DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday;
```

To check if a value contains the correct flag, you can use the AND operator :

```
bool isSundayAWeekend = (weekend & DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday) == DaysOfTheWeek.Sunday
```

Comment: I see the usage now, thank you!

Answer (score 7):

They are a combination of the `&` and `|` operators and assignment. `a &= b` is doing the same thing as `a = a & b`.

`&` and `|` are the bitwise *and* and *or* operators. `&` is the intersection of all bits in its operands, `|` is the union:

```
  10011100101
& 00100011110
-------------
  00000000100

  10011100101
| 00100011110
-------------
  10111111111
```

Basically, when you're using `&` on two numbers, all the bits are set that are set *in both* operands, while with `|`  all the bits are set that are set in *at least one* operand.

Comment: It's the same as `auto& temp = a; temp = temp & b;`

Comment: Hmm... could you explain what the purpose of that might be? It doesn't seem like the output is related (in terms of bytes anyway).

Comment: 0x6 is 110 in binary and 0xC is 1100. So the bitwise *and* of those two is 100, i.e. 4. If you look at the bytes or nibbles in question you usually don't see that easily (unless very familiar with the binary representation).

Comment: Sorry, I got that part, what I mean is how is it helpful? Lets say I am re-factoring some one else's code and I see these operators being used. What should I assume the process is being done for? Because it seems like the output is sort of random (to me).

Comment: You can use it for separating individual parts of an integer. Maybe you pack four bytes into one which you can retrieve with bitwise *and*  and bitwise shifts. You can treat a number just as a bitfield and individual bits mean something to you. With `|` you can set a bit and with `&` you can retrieve its value again.

Comment: @minitech: Oh right, didn't check the tags for this question.  C# actual behavior is more like `some.object.reference.field_or_prop &= b;` is equivalent to `var temp = some.object.reference; temp.field_or_prop = temp.field_or_prop & b;`

Answer (score 1):

These are shortcuts for the standard bitwise operators AND (&) and OR (|).

```
a &= 0x06;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = a & 0x06
```

For an explanation of AND and OR see [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Bitwise_operators).